# refresh method in checkboxradio not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of radio button  and when click on add button add new item in radio buttons but refresh method not working and give me error:

Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

```
at Function.error (VM80 jquery-1.12.4.js:253)
at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (VM81 jquery-ui.js:246)
at Function.each (VM80 jquery-1.12.4.js:370)
at jQuery.fn.init.each (VM80 jquery-1.12.4.js:137)
at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.<computed> [as checkboxradio] (VM81 jquery-ui.js:236)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_event_bind_ref:11)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (VM80 jquery-1.12.4.js:5226)
at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (VM80 jquery-1.12.4.js:4878)
```

here my code:

```js
$("input").checkboxradio();

var i = 4;
$(".add").click(function(e) {
  $("fieldset:first").append(' <label for="radio-' + i + '">London</label><input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-' + i + '">');
  i++;
});
$(".refresh").click(function(e) {
  $("input").checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h2>Radio Group</h2>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select a Location: </legend>
  <label for="radio-1">New York</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
  <label for="radio-2">Paris</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
  <label for="radio-3">London</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
</fieldset>
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="refresh">refresh</button>
```

Comment: What do you want to do with refresh?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating a new radio input when you click on *add* button but you are not initializing it with checkboxradio.

So when you call the *refresh* method on this last input it causes the error you are seeing.

If you want to call *refresh* on all inputs you should first initialize the checkbox you are creating:

```
$("input").checkboxradio();

var i = 4;
$(".add").click(function(e) {
    var id = 'radio-' + i;
    $("fieldset:first").append(' <label for="' + id + '">London</label><input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="' + id + '">');
    $('#' + id).checkboxradio();
    i++;
});
$(".refresh").click(function(e) {
    $("input").checkboxradio("refresh");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to add a separate class in New addition in Label and Input radio box and a little bit change in jQuery code. please see the below solution. Just add new class name as "extras" and use remove builtin attribute function.

```js
$("input").checkboxradio();

var i = 4;
$(".add").click(function(e) {
  $("fieldset:first").append(' <label class="extras" for="radio-' + i + '">London</label><input type="radio" class="extras" name="radio-1" id="radio-' + i + '">');
  i++;
});
$(".refresh").click(function(e) {
 // $("input").checkboxradio("refresh");
  $('.extras').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<h2>Radio Group</h2>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select a Location: </legend>
  <label for="radio-1">New York</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-1">
  <label for="radio-2">Paris</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-2">
  <label for="radio-3">London</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="radio-3">
</fieldset>
<button class="add">add</button>
<button class="refresh">refresh</button>
```